# How I can manage to fill listview with .dbf

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I'm trying to open .dbf via c# wpf and load it into a `ListView`, but I have no luck.

In my ViewModel:

```
public void DBF()
    {
        var databasePath = @"C:\Users\jesson\Desktop\FLCOLU_Building_Outline_Hints_308EL_section3_2180ER_QC.dbf";
        var connectionString = string.Format("DSN=dBase Files", databasePath);
        OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);

        connection.Open();

        var _command = connection.CreateCommand();
        var query = string.Format(@"SELECT * FROM C:\Users\jesson\Desktop\FLCOLU_Building_Outline_Hints_308EL_section3_2180ER_QC.dbf");
        string commandText = query;


        var _dataAdapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(commandText, connection);

        DataSet _dataSet = new DataSet();
        DataTable _dataTable = new DataTable();

        _dataSet.Reset();
        _dataAdapter.Fill(_dataSet);

        _dataTable = _dataSet.Tables[0];
        var rows = _dataTable.Rows;

        string userName = rows[0].ItemArray[1] as string;
        string password = rows[0].ItemArray[2] as string;

        UserDataVar = new InputDataSingle
        {
            UserName = userName,
            Password = password
        };

        connection.Close();

    }
```

Did I do something wrong?  Any other ideas?

Comment: Im trying to get the rows i cant load in to DataTable and it just jump into connection.Close()

Comment: are you able to fill DataTable ?

Comment: yes and get the rows of .dbf

Answer (score 0):

here you go. try below one.

```
string filename= //yourfilePath;
    string constr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="+ filename +";Extended Properties=dBASE IV;User ID=Admin;Password=;";
DataTable dt = new DataTable();   
 using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr))
                {
                    var sql = "select * from " + filename ;
                    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
                    con.Open();
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet(); ;
                    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                    da.Fill(ds);
dt  =ds.Tables[0]
                }
```

here how to pass data to listview or dataGrid.;

```
mylistview.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

**Condition**
 you have to create View to your ListView;

Comment: i tried it but i just got this 3x on my output window; 

(A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll)